# MS Teams protocol links are automatically opened with web app in Chrome

Tags: ubuntu, chrome, microsoft-teams

I would like to use the standalone MS Teams Linux App to open links, for some reason when I click on them and the web app automatically starts. The button "Join on the Teams app" doesn't work.
[image]